# if (variable assignment) syntax query (Swift)

Tags: swift, swift5

I am confused with what exactly this line,

```
if let fileList = fileList, let files = fileList.files
```

is doing. If I understand correctly, a conditional can only have a boolean as its parameter, so

```
let fileList = fileList, let files = fileList.files
```

should be either true or false. What exactly does this syntax do?

```
func updateDisplay() {
        updateButtons()
        
        if let fileList = fileList, let files = fileList.files {
            if files.count == 0 {
                output?.text = "Folder is empty"
                table?.isHidden = true
            } else {
                table?.isHidden = false
                table?.reloadData()
            }
        }
        else {
            output?.text = ""
            table?.isHidden = true
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `let a = b` syntax used in an if statement is called optional binding. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID333). Essentially, if `b` is nil, the condition is treated as "false". If `b` is not nil, the condition is treated as "true", and a non optional constant `a` will now have the value that `b` has, and you can use it inside the if block.

Swift if statements also allow you to specify multiple conditions. All of them has to be "true" for the if block to be executed. These conditions doesn't have to be boolean expressions. They could be any of the following:

- Boolean expressions
- Optional Binding
- `#available` check
- `case` pattern matching

If you have two boolean expressions and you want to run some code if both of them are true, you *could* use `&&` to join them together, but if you have 2 optionals that you want to bind, or one boolean expression and one optional binding, or any combination of the above, you'd need to use a comma to separate the conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It confused the heck out of me trying to logically figure out what it was.

Answer (score 1):

```
if let fileList = fileList, let files = fileList.files {
```

is actually an assignment statement with a test for "null".  If the assignment succeeds, then carry out the code inside the braces.  The boolean test for equality in swift is `==`.